# Reprojecting NetCDF file from LCC to WGS84: 'Multiple grid mappings exist' error

Tags: coordinate-system, rasterio, netcdf, proj, rioxarray

I try to reproject a NetCDF file to WGS84 so I can clip it with a regional geometry for analysis. The file is a dataset with the CORDEX precipitation variable, climate change scenario rcp 2.6, years 2021-2031, acquired from the  Copernicus climate data store. Code:

```
import rioxarray as rioxr
import rasterio

ds_path =  r'pr_EUR-11_CNRM-CERFACS-CNRM-CM5_rcp26_r1i1p1_CNRM-ALADIN63_v2_mon_202101-203012.nc' # the downloded file from COPERNICUS climate data store

ds = rioxr.open_rasterio(ds_path) # open the file with rioxr

dataset=copy.copy(ds[1]) # for an unknown to me reason ds is a list, the 2nd item is the dataset I want
```

The xarray dataset is like this (and it seems it has an LCC projection):

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:            (time: 120, x: 453, y: 453, band: 1)
Coordinates:
  * time               (time) object 2021-01-16 12:00:00 ... 2030-12-16 12:00:00
  * x                  (x) float64 0.0 12.5 25.0 ... 5.638e+03 5.65e+03
  * y                  (y) float64 5.65e+03 5.638e+03 5.625e+03 ... 12.5 0.0
    Lambert_Conformal  int32 0
  * band               (band) int32 1
    spatial_ref        int32 0
Data variables:
    pr                 (time, y, x) float32 ...
    lon                (band, y, x) float64 ...
    lat                (band, y, x) float64 ...
Attributes: (12/59)
    Lambert_Conformal#grid_mapping_name:              lambert_conformal_conic
    Lambert_Conformal#latitude_of_projection_origin:  49.5
    Lambert_Conformal#longitude_of_central_meridian:  10.5
    Lambert_Conformal#standard_parallel:              49.5
    c3s_disclaimer:                                   This data has been prod...
    comment:                                          CORDEX Europe EUR-11 CN...
                                              ...
    x#standard_name:                                  projection_x_coordinate
    x#units:                                          km
    y#axis:                                           Y
    y#long_name:                                      y coordinate of projection
    y#standard_name:                                  projection_y_coordinate
    y#units:                                          km
```

I proceed to reproject a slice of the dataset:

```
timestamps= dataset.time #get the timestamps to slice

precip_slice=copy.copy(dataset.sel(time=timestamps[1])) 

precip_slice.spatial_ref #this prints:
```

```
<xarray.DataArray 'spatial_ref' ()>
array(0)
Coordinates:
    time               object 2021-02-15 00:00:00
    Lambert_Conformal  int32 0
    spatial_ref        int32 0
Attributes:
    GeoTransform:  -6.25 12.5 0.0 5656.25 0.0 -12.5
```

If I do this:

```
precip_reproj= precip_slice.rio.reproject("EPSG:4326")
```

I get an `CRS not found. Please set the CRS with 'rio.write_crs()'. Data variable: lon'`

Then I write a new crs with proj4, hoping I do get the inputs for this LCC right:

```
crs= rasterio.crs.CRS.from_proj4('+proj=lcc +10.5=-90 +49.5=33 +lat_2=45')
```

And try to set the CRS to the file with:

```
precip_slice=precip_slice.rio.write_crs(crs, inplace=True)
```

But it fails with this:

```
    precip_slice=precip_slice.rio.write_crs(crs)

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\drought_study\lib\site-packages\rioxarray\rioxarray.py:478 in write_crs
    transform = self._cached_transform()

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\drought_study\lib\site-packages\rioxarray\rioxarray.py:575 in _cached_transform
    self._obj.coords[self.grid_mapping].attrs["GeoTransform"], sep=" "

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\drought_study\lib\site-packages\rioxarray\rioxarray.py:391 in grid_mapping
    raise RioXarrayError("Multiple grid mappings exist.")

RioXarrayError: Multiple grid mappings exist.
```

It seems that the dataset already has a mapping (it already has a Geotransform attribute?) but somehow it is not recognized at the reproject method?